# stop bash try to display every possible result and auto-complete when ambiguous result find

Tags: bash

This is my `.inputrc`

```
  9 set show-all-if-unmodified on
 10 set menu-complete-display-prefix on
 11 #set completion-ignore-case on
 12 set disable-completion on
```

1) How do I stop bash try to display every possible result, but just list the results same as I do with `ls`?

Current behavior:

```
[11:56:33dev@srv:~/test/config$ [Tab]
Display all 1643 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Desired behavior:

`[11:39:07]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ls[Tab]
a.ini  config.ini  environment.ini  mappings.csv  market.ini trace.ini`

2) How do I stop my bash auto-complete when ambiguous result find, but only show the list of possible results?

Current behavior:

```
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./ma[Tab]
mappings.csv  market.ini
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./mappings.csv
```

Desired behavior:

```
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./ma[Tab]
mappings.csv  market.ini
[12:04:50]dev@srv:~/test/config$ ./ma
```

Comment: Actually, reading the question again now, I may have misunderstood. I thought you just meant that you don't want `bash` to ask if it should list everything. So if you don't want all results in 1), what do you actually want? All files in your current directory every time? Elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick browse through the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax), to solve the first issue, try this:

```
set completion-query-items -1
set page-completions off
```

> `completion-query-items`
>
> The number of possible completions that determines when the user is
>   asked whether the list of possibilities should be displayed. A
>   negative value means Readline should never ask.

---

The second issue (since you are using `./`) might actually be that one of the files is marked executable whereas the second is not. Take a look at this snippet:

```
$ touch foo foobar
$ ./fo<TAB>               # neither file is executable so nothing is completed
$ chmod +x foo
$ ./fo<TAB>                  
$ ./foo                   # foo is the only file executable and is completed
$ chmod +x foobar
$ ./foo<TAB>                 
./foo ./foobar            # both files are executable and the completion is now ambiguous
```

Try to do `cat ma<TAB>` to see if the behavior is as expected.